# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token when inserting CDATA

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to copy the behavior of jsfiddle on my page, meaning a user can submit some javascript, and it will be rendered within an iframe. However, my test code is failing, and the js is working on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sgagz995/). Any help is super appreciated!!!

**Error message on my page:**

```
VM16741:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

**When I click on VM16741:2 I get the following:**

```
\\<![CDATA[
    window.onload=function() {
document.querySelector('.test').style.backgroundColor="rgb(21, 160, 249)";
}//]]>
```

**Inspecting the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sgagz995/)'s output you will see in the head:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 //<![CDATA[
 window.onload=function(){
 document.querySelector('.test').style.backgroundColor="rgb(21, 160, 249)"; 
 }//]]> 
</script>
```

**Here is my code (which I believe is identical except for whitespace):**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
\\<![CDATA[
    window.onload=function() {
document.querySelector('.test').style.backgroundColor="rgb(21, 160, 249)";
}//]]>
</script>
```

**Here is the output to the iframe on my web page's test:**

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
    .test { display:inline-flex; padding:40px; background-color:#cccccc }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
\\<![CDATA[
    window.onload=function() {
document.querySelector('.test').style.backgroundColor="rgb(21, 160, 249)";
}//]]>
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="test">test</div>
</body></html>
```

**Here is the js I use to insert css, html, and js into the iframe:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {


  var html = //some html here - works
  var css = //some css here - works
  var js = //some js here - fails

  var sandbox = $('.sandboxed');
  sandbox.ready(function() {
    var htmlContainer = document.createElement('div');
    var cssContainer = document.createElement('style');
    var jsContainer = document.createElement('script');
    jsContainer.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    var head = sandbox.contents().find('head');
    var body = sandbox.contents().find('body');
    $(head).append(cssContainer);
    $(head).append(jsContainer);
    $(html).append(htmlContainer);
    $(cssContainer).append('\n\t'+css+'\n');
    $(jsContainer).text('\n\\\\<![CDATA[\n\twindow.onload=function() {\n'+js+'\n}//]]>\n');
    body.prepend(html);
  });

});
```

**If I expand the error I get the following message:**

```
(anonymous function)    @   jquery.min.js:3
each    @   jquery.min.js:2
each    @   jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous function)    @   jquery.min.js:3
S   @   jquery.min.js:2
text    @   jquery.min.js:3
(anonymous function)    @   sandbox.js:20
j   @   jquery.min.js:2
k   @   jquery.min.js:2
```

Comment: Your slashes are different. Look closely at the code you re-typed.

Comment: It is `//` for comments, not \\. Just a typo. Vote for close.

Comment: awesome thanks @Blender

Comment: @eisbehr thank you!